# Check if MKPolygon is inside visible rect or another MKPolygon

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkmapview

I have a MKMapview with lot of polygons added as overlays, To optimize the memory I need to know before adding an overlay if the polygon is inside visible area of the MKMapview

I can even create a whole visible area polygon with mapview all corner coordinates, for example topLeft as below

```
func topLeftCoordinate() -> CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        return convert(bounds.origin, toCoordinateFrom: self)
}
```

with all the corner coordinates, I can create a current_visible_area_polygon and I want to check the polygons I add is inside this current_visible_area_polygon.

so it comes down to two questions

1. Is it possible to check if a polygon is inside another polygon or atleast intersects OR
2. if a polygon is inside visible maprect

Comment: This looks like it may be helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16547575/creating-a-new-mkpolygon-from-two-intersecting-polygons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to be the following

```
let mapView: MKMapView
let mkPolygon: MKPolygon

mapView.visibleMapRect.isIntersects(mkPolygon)
```